# How to get every values for a specific attribute id by product id?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, url, products

What I am trying to do is to create a link from the parent URL to preselect some attributes for a configurable product. For example. http://localhost/magento-product/#{attribute_id} = {value}. I want to do this for all products that contains these attributes that requires for example size/color. Is there a dynamically way to do this?

Comment: Yes.it positionable. Are u using default magento  theme

Comment: Yes, that's what I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code tested in Magento 1.9.2.3

```
<?php            
include('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();  

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(875);
if($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'){
  $type = $product->getTypeInstance(true);
  foreach($type->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product) as $attribute){
     echo $attribute['id']."\n"; 
     echo $attribute['attribute_id']."\n"; //attribute id that is in Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes    
     foreach($attribute['values'] as $v) 
      echo $v['label']."\n";    //value 
      echo $v['value_index']."\n"; //value id                                                                                                                                                


  }             
}
```

Then you can use either `$attribute['id'] and $v['label']` or `$attribute['id'] and $v['value_index']`

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply, what If I got a simple product, and I want to see which super attributes that product have? Like size/color/etc. ? I found out how to find the value id for 'color', 'size' but I wanna see dynamically for each simple product how many attributes of those kind it got and get the value id specific